# Remove array without any value or key

Tags: php, arrays

I have these array

```
Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => B
    [2] => C
    [3] => D
)
Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => B
    [2] => C
    [3] => D
)
Array
(
)
```

But the last array don't have any key or value, i want to remove it, please help !

Comment: This output seems like from a loop. Show us your code and how you get those outputs.

Comment: unset($emptyArray)? Where do they come from, are they all values of some bigger array or are they all assigned to different variables, etc.?

Comment: @TamVao, you have asked for help, could you add more context(code) so we can recognize why `array_filter` function doesn't fit for solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Use array_filter for this task, assuming this is part of a parent array.

```
array_filter($arrs);
```

This will remove empty arrays for you.

Comment: It just work with array have both value and no value, but last array i show don't have any value !

Comment: Are they not all part of another array? I need to see more code.